# Node.js MySQL strings being treated as commands

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using the MySQL module to run database commands but am getting SQL errors on strings like:

"previously discussed, I do not" or by having the % symbol in them.

Is there a way to clean these so MySQL doesn't fall over?

Example SQL

```
var sql = 'update Meetings set Notes = "' + data.Notes + '" where MeetingID = ' + data.meetingID + ';';
```

Comment: What module are you using for querying?

Comment: Do you properly escape the data received as an input before trying to submit it as part of a query?

Comment: Provide the sql if possible

Comment: As stated using mysql module. I thought that mysql did escaping on the data?